# Grub rescue error: Unknown Commands + Unknown FileSystem + Live Usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, live-usb, grubrescue

I have been given an Asus EEE Pc 1201PN where Ubuntu and Windows 7 used to live in a dual-boot. When running Windows 7, the Ubuntu partition has been erased and thus, Grub is not working anymore when restarting the computer.

- I have downloaded [BootRepair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) and installed it on a USB drive.
- Bios Boot Device Priority is "Removable Dev." then "USB Flash Disk" then "HDD"
- Boot Booster is Disabled

When I boot the computer (and press ESC to check the Boot Selection Menu) I can see my USB Flash Disk.

So I select USB and expect to run Boot Repair ... However after a few second of black screen I finally reach the:

```
error: no such partition
grub rescue>
```

I can see the USB drive, which is hd1:

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1)
```

So I check where grub is looking the /grub folder:

```
grub rescue> set
prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos5
```

hd0,msdos5 does not exist, I suppose it was were the Ubuntu partition used to be.

Now I set the new /grub folder location to my USB drive:

```
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd1)/boot/grub
grub rescue> set root=hd1
grub rescue> set
prefix=(hd1)/boot/grub
root=hd1
```

Now the fun begin ...

```
grub rescue> insmod normal
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue> ls /
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue> ls (hd1)/
error: unknown filesystem
```

Grub does not know isnmod ??? Since when isnmod has been implemented in grub ? 
Chain loader command is not working as well as root, ...
I am pretty sure the release which is installed in this computer is from late 2013.

I check my USB drive and everything seems alright.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqUiK.png)

Right now I have no idea how to boot on my USB drive and repair the computer boot.

If you have any idea how to overcome this issue, you are welcome ! I have check many many links dealing with this issue, but no one worked :(

Thanks !

Comment: `isnmod`? Maybe `insmod` :)

Comment: Hum, typo !
With insmod normal I got "error: unknown filesystem"

(I am modifying my original post)

Comment: How did you install Boot-Repair to flash drive? It seems flash drive is not bootable, and BIOS is defaulting to hard drive with broken grub. Many just install Boot-Repair to their standard Ubuntu installer in live boot mode.

Comment: I followed the MacOSX section of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromImgFiles with the bootRepair32bit file from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

I will try to install a live Ubuntu but unetbootin seems to generate non-bootable flash drive when running on Mac

Comment: Either using unebootin or the direct approach with terminal, I still have the unknown filesystem error. I did not check the USB drive on an other PC system but I am pretty sure everything is OK, and I do not see why it can't be bootable :/

Comment: Ok I managed to launch a Live Ubuntu on my USB drive :) I installed boot-repair but the MBR options menu is unavailable :/